# How to reset the buffer value in xmltask?

Tags: ant, xmltask

I'm new to xmltask. Since im using xmltask to copy and insert nodes. My problem is, i used to store the copied values into buffer rather using the property. The copied values will be inserted based on the loop(it might run for 3 times). So when its processing into the loop, the buffer values are appended for next consequent run, where i enabled append is true. Btw i need to proceed with reset of copied buffers for my next run of the loop.  Is there any way to bring solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [xmltask manual](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/), xmltask attribute `clearBuffers` :

> Clears buffers after population by previous xmltask invocations.
>   Buffers are cleared after every input file is processed. Buffers are
>   specified in a comma-delimited string